# RadComboBoxItemCollection not wotrking with linq

Tags: linq, extension-methods, telerik

I'm creating some extension methods and I'm getting some errors with RadComboBoxItemCollection,  RadComboBoxItemCollection appears to implement IEnumerable but linq keeps giving me errors saying:

> "Could not find an implementation of
>   the query pattern for source type
>   'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemCollection'.
>   'Where' not found.  Consider
>   explicitly specifying the type of the
>   range variable 'myItem'."

from this code

```
public static bool ContainsValue(this RadComboBoxItemCollection myList, string value)
{
      bool matches = (from myItem in myList where myItem.Value == value select myItem).Count() > 0;
      return matches;
}
```

on the flip side RadListBoxItemCollection works just fine

```
public static bool ContainsValue(this IEnumerable<RadListBoxItem> myList, string value)
{
      bool matches = (from myItem in myList where myItem.Value == value select myItem).Count() > 0;
      return matches;
}
```

I tried doing IEnumerable and this solves the linq errors but I get this error

> "Instance argument: cannot convert
>   from
>   'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemCollection'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RadComboBoxItemCollection implements the non-generic IEnumerable interface (rather than doing the sensible thing and implementing IEnumerable<RadComboBoxItem>), so your standard LINQ operations won't work. You would have to use the "Cast" extension method first:

```
 var result = myList.Items.Cast<RadComboBoxItem>();
```

Now you have a much more useful IEnumerable<RadComboBoxItem> that you can do all sorts of wonderful things with:

```
public static bool ContainsValue(this RadComboBoxItemCollection myList, string value)
{
      return myList.Items.Cast<RadComboBoxItem>().Count(item => item.Value.Equals(value, StringComparison.Ordinal)) > 0;
}
```

However, someone with more experience than me could probably speak to the performance of this approach; it might be better for performance to just do it the old (pre-LINQ) way rather than casting each object to a RadComboBoxItem:

```
public static bool ContainsValue(this RadComboBoxItemCollection myList, string value)
{
      foreach (var item in myList)
          if (item.Value.Equals(value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
              return true;

      return false
}
```

Comment: you where right, I used a similar fix using a for loop, Telerik is updating there controls to fix this issue